# Get SUM for same column but different relationships

Tags: mysql, join, sum, relationship

I'm working on this database for a pet clinic (learning exercise), and what I want to do is to get the SUM for the same column, but different relationships.

These are my tables (only listing attributes used in query):

> customer (**customer_id**, customer_name)
>
> employee (**employee_id**, first_name, last_name)
>
> pet (**pet_id**, owner_id, pet_name)
>
> performed_service (**performed_services_id**, visit_id, service_id)
>
> visit (**visit_id**, customer_id, employee_id, pet_id, date)
>
> service (**service_id**, name, cost)

This is the query that I've tried, which so far gets all the data that I want, but not the SUMS correctly, which I cannot seem to understand how to do (if at all possible). What I'm trying to do is fetch the sum for service.cost for each pets visit, and sum of service.cost for all the visits that the customer has had, later I'm going to add a where clause on the date, so that it only shows instances of the current date:

```
    SELECT 
    customer.customer_name, 
    pet.pet_name, 
    visit.date,
    CONCAT(employee.first_name, ' ', employee.last_name) AS 'Veterenarian',
    performed_service.service_id, 
    service.name AS 'Treatment', 
    service.cost AS 'Price', 
    SUM(service.cost) AS 'Pet Total', 
    SUM(service.cost) AS 'Customer Total'

    FROM visit

    INNER JOIN customer
    ON visit.customer_id=customer.customer_id

    INNER JOIN employee
    ON visit.employee_id=employee.employee_id

    INNER JOIN pet
    ON visit.pet_id=pet.pet_id

    INNER JOIN performed_service
    ON visit.visit_id=performed_service.visit_id

    INNER JOIN service
    ON performed_service.service_id=service.service_id

    GROUP BY performed_service.performed_service_id
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you try to reformat your code so it's readable? It's pretty hard to read and understand what you're trying to do as is.

Comment: Sorry, first time using StackOverflow. What I want to do is for every performed_service that is reported for the current date, add a column that represents the sum of all the performed services' cost during the pets visit, called 'Pet Total'. I also want a total that combines the 'Pet Totals' on the current date, related to the customer as a column called 'Customer Total'.

Comment: Your  `SUM(service.cost) AS 'Pet Total'` and `SUM(service.cost) AS 'Customer Total'` should give you the same result and they should give you at least one of your desired result, right?

Comment: Right now it only gives me the cost of each service related, since I'm grouping by performed_service_id. I think I have found the solution, which is to select a subquery that fetches the desired relationships and then connect it to the outer query. I will update once I finish implementing it.